# Facebook Graph API authorization problem

Tags: facebook, authorization

If I load the following URL in Firefox and login to Facebook, I'm getting a page displaying "An invalid next or cancel parameter was specified."

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=c8caf78d724d142ee82334131ef5c9ce&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent&display=touch&scope=offline_access,publish_stream

But if I change the display parameter to display=page I no longer get this error.  Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Are you sure? It worked perfectly for me:)

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to try the suggestion below and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable New Data Permissions on the Migrations tab in your app's settings.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Yup, it worked.  Thanks.  In what part of the documentation did you find this?

Comment: I was just browsing through the app settings a few days ago and googled this perticular setting.

Comment: UPDATE: Facebook migrated all apps to the New Data Permissions a few days ago.